# Why when I try to bind a function to itself does the "this" object still refer to the window?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = function() {

  alert( this ); // [object Window]
  alert(  a   ); // undefined

}.call( a );
```

Why does `this` still refer to the window object and `a` undefined. Alternatively, when I do it the following way, `this` is equal to the function `a` is not undefined.

```
var a = function() {

  return this === a; // true

};

a.call(a);
```

Can anyone explain why these two functions that are seemingly equivalent give different results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in your first example `a` isn't assigned until after the call to your function completes.

In detail, here's what happens in the first example:

1. The anonymous function is defined.
2. The function is called using `a` as the `this` parameter.
3. The function executes, but because `a` is still undefined, `this` falls back to `window` instead.
4. The function returns `undefined`, which is assigned to `a`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var a = function() {

  alert( this ); // [object Window]
  alert(  a   ); // undefined

}.call( a );
```

`a` here becomes the result of evaluating the function: that is, `a = (function() { ... }).call(a)`, not the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, `a` isn't assigned until after the function is called, therefore `a` is undefined.

Answer (score -2):

Try it like this,

```
var a = function() {...}
a.call(a)
```

Comment: The question (asked three years ago) already has an accepted answer. You should only add an answer if it adds sufficiently more information to justify a new answer with a question this old instead of an edit to an existing answer or a comment. The OP asked for an explanation, and this provides none. It also doesn't add anything more to the accepted answer.